# Create a CByteArray from a CPointer in Visual Works Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

Some C function return `aCPointer` to a `C struct`.
The `C struct` is known.
Now i want to put the `C struct` into a `ByteArray`. Basically copy the contents of the struct to a `ByteArray`.
In **GemStone/S** this can be done with:
`CByteArray fromCPointer: aCPointer numBytes: 120.` 
"this create aCByteArray with the contents of the struct referenced by CPointer (copying only 120 bytes)"

Is there something similar on Visual Works ?
I did not find it yet.
It could be possible to replicate C struct at Visual Works level but is only one struct and it is ok to handle it at low level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only the rather ugly `#copyAt:to:size:startingAt:` that you can send to a pointer. You need to allocate a `ByteArray` yourself (make sure it's big enough).

```
answer := ByteArray new: size.
pointer
        copyAt: 0
        to: answer
        size: size
        startingAt: 1.
```

The other way (ByteArray -> Pointer) would be done using `#copyAt:from:size:startingAt:`.

This method works for both `ByteArray` and `UninterpretedBytes`. If you want to read data from the bytes, `UninterpretedBytes` may be more helpful as you can send things like `#longAt:` to read a `long` from an offset.

Comment: UninterpretedBytes is very handy. How ever if the C struct is like:
struct FileAttr 
{char * name;
char * longname;
uint32_t flags;
uint8_t type;
uint64_t size;
char * owner;} fileAttr;
I'm able to read all values above but not "owner". aCPointer>>at: and aCPointer>>copyAt:to:size:startingAt: does not get the value of "owner". Which is rather strange because i can read the others values.

Comment: "owner" can be accessed with aCPointer at: 8 where 8 = byteNumberWhereTheOwnerAddressStart / 4

Comment: you should definitely think about just defining a C-Struct in your `ExternalInterface`. It's so much easier to access the members in a structure via `memberAt:`, than fiddling with the offsets yourself. You should have a look at the `DLLandCConnectGuide.pdf` in the `doc` folder of your VisualWorks installation. Chapter 2 and 3 should cover the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If `aCPointer` points to a struct of char * for example:

```
struct Names 
{char * name;
char * longname;} name;
```

Then:

```
(aCPointer at: 0) copyCStringFromHeap. "answer [name]"
(aCPointer at: 1) copyCStringFromHeap. "answer [longname]"
```

For structs with char * it work nicely not tested with other C types.